# XPath escape characters (HtmlUnit)

Tags: java, html, xpath, htmlunit, html-escape-characters

I'm using HtmlUnit and as such I'm using XPath.
I'm trying to find an element with an attribute with a certain value, however my results are returning nothing. I suspect this is due to the nature of the symbols that are in this value: "**$**" and "**=**".
An example of the element I am trying to pull is:

```
<span data-reactid=".3.1.0.0.1:1.0.1.0.1:$0.$=12:$2.2">
```

And the code I am using to try and pull it is:

```
page.getFirstByXPath("//span[@data-reactid='.3.1.0.0.1:1.0.1.0.1:$0.$=12:$2.2']");
```

I imagine it is the dollar sign if anything as I doubt an equals sign would present a problem, but perhaps I'm completely wrong.

My question is, a) is it indeed to do with escape characters, and b) if not, why else would the results not be pulling in what I want?

Can post more code if required, but I imagine this will be enough.

Thank you!

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong with your XPath.  We'll probably need enough code and HTML input to be able to reproduce the problem.

Comment: What does `'//span'` give you?

Answer (score 1):

The below works, probably you have an issue of your page not related to XPath, e.g. Element not found

Html code:

```
<html>
<body>
<span data-reactid=".3.1.0.0.1:1.0.1.0.1:$0.$=12:$2.2">
</span>
</body>
</html>
```

Java Code:

```
try (WebClient webClient = new WebClient()) {
    HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://localhost/test.html");
    Object o = page.getByXPath("//span[@data-reactid='.3.1.0.0.1:1.0.1.0.1:$0.$=12:$2.2']");
    System.out.println(o);
}
```

Comment: This is misleading. XPath does not define any escaping mechanisms for strings. Escaping inside an XPath string is *never* necessary, the "latest snapshot" has nothing to do with it at all.

Comment: You are right, but I always test with latest snapshot in case someone use an old version

Comment: That's commendable, but your answer makes it sound as if by any chance that would make a difference. It is, in fact, literally impossible to do character escaping in XPath strings. Always has been. It's in the spec that way. So whatever the OP is doing, the version of the software he uses is completely irrelevant.

Comment: Thank you, it turned out to be a flaw in my understanding. I've posted my learnings as an answer.

Comment: What about the ":" (colon) character, when not used as part of a namespace? I have code that returns the element name as "media:thumbnail" - What XPath can I use to find that?

Answer (score 1):

So I figured this out myself, thanks for help everyone who posted.
In the order that I posed the questions:
**a)** Character escaping is impossible in XPath strings, so it wasn't anything to do with what I suspected.
**b)** The reason it wasn't pulling in what I wanted was due to a simple misunderstanding of XPath syntax.
I thought that `//span[@data-reactid='.3.1.0.0.1:1.0.1.0.1:$0.$=12:$2.2']` would find the first `<span>` element with the given attribute and value, but actually it was finding the first element with the given attribute and value, **within** a `<span>` element, regardless of whether it was a `<span>` element itself. Therefore the XPath was actually returning a `<strong>` element that had the same `data-reactid` value, so that when I called `.getTextContent()` on the returned `HtmlElement`, there was no text to be returned.

Comment: Can you give a minimal HTML/java case for returning a <strong>, please? and does it match what real browsers do?

Comment: I'm unsure what you're asking?

Comment: //span returning a <strong> is an error, and I tried to reproduce that error without success.  If you can provide HTML where //span returns strong, so it can be investigated further, and fixed in HtmlUnit.

Comment: Maybe it wasn't the exact code up there then, I may have tweaked it and forgot, but whatever the case I was definitely using "span" in my xpath, and getting a strong element returned. Might have been a slash or so different but I can't remember now